# Any documents about signature blobs' structure except codeDirectory on MacOS

Tags: macos, codesign, mach-o

A signed macho file has a section named "signature", and the signature includes several blobs.

I know that we can use 'codesign' in bash to get the signature info about a macho file which was signed.
And there is a tool named "JTool"(http://newosxbook.com/tools/jtool.html). 
JTool can give you more info than the "codesign", such as the hashes in codeDirecory blob.

But JTool is not open scurce. And when I tried to repeat this function in JTool to show more details about signature, I have found a document about the blobs' structure named 'codesign.h' on apple site. (http://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-2422.1.72/bsd/sys/codesign.h)

Now I have parsed the codeDirectory's data. But I failed to parse other blobs. All I know about other blob is the info provided by 'codesign.h':

```
typedef struct __SC_GenericBlob {
uint32_t magic;             /* magic number */
uint32_t length;            /* total length of blob */
char data[];}CS_GenericBlob;
```

I have tried to parse the data by using the char type, and failed. The result was messy code. So I considered that there is more detailed structure about other blobs.

Is there any document can help me parse other blobs?